# Como deixar os 4 em uma fileira só?

Tags: html, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```
<div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 my-4 mx-auto">
            <h2 class="text-center display-4">Bootstrap 4 Pricing Tables</h2>

            <hr>
            <div class="row no-gutters my-3">
                <div class="col-md-4 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Felipe, você já deixou claro que é bootstrap ao colocar a tag. Não precisa colocar no título. Sem falar que o título começando com minúscula não segue a norma culta da escrita, e sempre que possível deve-se aderir à ela (exceto se o autor do conteúdo está deliberadamente fugindo por questões estilísticas textuais, mas não é o seu caso com o título)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma row em Bootstrap vale 12

Se você quer 4 coluna, o seu `col-md-4 pl-2` deveria ser `col-md-3 pl-2`
porque você tem 4 elementos somando os `col-md-4` da 16, que resulta em duas linhas row 1 = 12 e row 2 = 4

```
<div class="container py-4">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 my-4 mx-auto">
            <h2 class="text-center display-4">Bootstrap 4 Pricing Tables</h2>

            <hr>
            <div class="row no-gutters my-3">
                <div class="col-md-3 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 pl-2">
                    <div class="list-group text-center my-3">
                        <div href="#" class="list-group-item text-white bg-dark">
                            <h4 class="text-center my-1">Managed</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="list-group-item text-uppercase font-weight-bold">
                            Contact Us
                        </div>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Upto 10 TB HDD Storage
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Consultation
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            Custom Servers
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                            24/7 Support
                        </a>
                        <div class="list-group-item">
                            <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg btn-block text-truncate">Contact Us</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <hr>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Troca as classes do containner de cada div:

Está assim:

```
<div class="col-md-4 pl-2">
```

Mude para:

```
<div class="col-md-3 pl-2">
```

[Leia mais](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp) sobre a Grid System do bootstrap

Comment: Um print ou um snippet executável seria apreciado. Snippet executável seria especialmente apreciado

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado ainda nao aprendi como usar o snippet executavel, se puder deiche um link onde explica como.

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam Tem essa explicação https://butecoopensource.github.io/stack-overflow-introduz-snippets-javascript-css-e-html-executaveis/, mas é auto-intuitivo. Bem semelhante ao `codepen`, `jsfiddle` etc.